# Использование обработчиков в Ansible

Tags: python, ansible

Добрый день. Я написал роль для zookeeper и решил добавить обработчик который будет остуществлять рестарт сервиса. Собственно, я создал папку handlers в нем лежит файл main.yml следующего вида:

```
---

- name: restart zookeeper
  systemd: name=zookeeper state=restarted
```

Структура роли:

```
    k.zookeeper
    ├── defaults
    │   └── main.yml
    ├── handlers
    │   └── main.yml
    ├── tasks
    │   ├── configure.yml
    │   ├── install.yml
    │   ├── main.yml
    │   └── push.yml
    └── templates
        ├── myid.j2
        └── zoo.cfg.j2
```

После конфигурации небходимо перезапустить сервис с помощью обработчика. Я должен прописать notify в сам configure.yml или в main.yml?
Благодарю за внимание!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Невозможно точно ответить на ваш вопрос.

`notify` нужно делать на всех задачах, которые требуют рестарта сервиса – например, запись конфигурационных файлов.
Если такие задачи описаны в configure.yml – значит там, если в mail.yml – там.

Таким образом если при выполнении плейбука у задач с маркировкой `notify: restart zookeeper` будет статус `changed`, то обработчик выполнится в конце роли.